# Yii - View protected PDF files

Tags: php, pdf, yii, protected

In my application, there are some PDF files that users upload to server. These are private files and they cannot have global visibility.

I'm trying to upload these files to a protected directory (**/protected/uploads**, for example). The users must be able to view these files, but they must **not** be visible by the client browser.
Something like an "internal view" of my application.

How can I do that?
If I use the "assets" directory the files will be global visible, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the right header and perform a readfile such as:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="yourPDF.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

This will open the file in the browser as you requested and will prevent the user to grab it directly.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I had found a similar solution in another topic, but it's not quite what I was looking for. Well, I think it'll have to be this way. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by it's not quite what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, basically I would like to embed the PDF files in my application. More or less like this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/qpdfjs/

Comment: But _qpdfjs_ must have the files setted by URL, turning the files public

Comment: You can still have the URL for example /pdf/view/id/1 which will return the header posted above. I am not sure how your application is set up but you could use access rules in your controller to prevent non logged in user to access this action.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter

Comment: Man.... what a shame! You're completely right! I was trying so many things in the past few days that I messed all up! :)   
Now I can do in the way I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is a method on the request component, `sendFile`. It's briefly described here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#redirect-detail

Usage would be:

```
Yii::app()->request->sendFile($filename, $content);
```

`$filename` will be what you want the file users download to be called

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but this method will download the file. I need to view the file in the browser